# (C#) Struggle to migrate Console.App code to WIndows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, console, hexdump

I need to convert this console code to `WinForms` code.
This code for `HexDump` format of recevieng data. I tried to convert 
`Console.WriteLine(Hex.Dump(example))` to `textBox4.Text (Hex.Dump(example))`
I don't know is it correct or not, and still struggle with converting `Console.OutputEncoding`.

```
    Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
    byte[] example = Enumerable.Range(0, 256).Select(x => (byte)x).ToArray();
    Console.WriteLine(Hex.Dump(example));
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: use RichTextBox instead of Textbox so there will be no need of  Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
and 
RichTextBox.Text = (Hex.Dump(example)) should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasnt working code, dont use it